# How to import `mp3` files in rhythmbox music player?

Tags: 14.04, rhythmbox

How can I import MP3 files into Rhythmbox music player?

Here's what I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get restricted extras
```

Answer (score 3):

1. open rhythmbox
2. click **file --> add music**
3. select folder location of your music, click **Open**

the list should load your mp3 file

4. Click "import x listed tracks" button (x is amount of mp3 files you have in the folder you choose earlier)

Comment: i can't see import in my rhythmbox player ?

Comment: It's in the Music Tab. You should see track listing and above it Edit | Browse | View All | Import

Comment: hey, i forgot the fourth step and just updated the post.